# How to find all flights scheduled between a pair of cities?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I am waiting for someone to fly in this week, but have no idea when they are arriving and can't contact them. I looked online and found flight trackers, but they only show flights already "en route" or that have recently arrived. I know both airports, but there's no way I can narrow down when the person would be leaving to know when they are arriving.

I know it's not possible to get flight info using someone's name as that is a breach of privacy, but is there any way to get a list of booked flights and their departures from and to airports to get a better idea of arrival/departure times between travels? Obviously not by name though.

This should help me figure when my friend would be arriving if I knew a list of booked flights so I could figure which ones they'd be getting on based on the time differences from where we are.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: It may be possible if you know the day, the two airports, and the airline. Otherwise it is probably not possible.

Comment: You mean you want to have schedules for all flights between a pair of cities? If that's not what you mean, you'll need to be clearer. What do you mean by "booked flights"? Booked by whom?

Comment: Do you have reason to think the passenger has a nonstop flight?  If you know the origin and destination airports, but they may have a connection in between, it gets a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get "booked" flight lists, but you can get "scheduled" flights.

Try to search Google for Destination Airport official website. They must have a schedule of departures & arrivals, look into arrivals list. But if your friend has a transit somewhere in between of journey, the arrival will list the last transit airport as origin.

For example, the website of Doha Airport will list AbuDhabi as origin for Delhi-AbuDhabi-Doha flight.

Second option, if you know the airline, look at airline's website for flights between your two original cities. Apart from all scheduled flights, it may also give you an idea of transits, if any.